# pfSense & VMWare ESXi VLAN integration

Tags: vlan, pfsense, vmware

Were setting up a pfsense box as a virtual machine inside a VMWare ESXi 6.0 environment ([inside a VXRail hyper-converged Box](https://www.emc.com/en-us/converged-infrastructure/vxrail/index.htm)).

The target configuration is that to access any machine within this box, you need to go through the Firewall. Traffic between machines within the same box also need to go through the firewall. Since they are different servers e.g. Web Server, Database Server, the VMs are setup to be in different VLANs.

As such, we've setup pfSense with two interfaces. One is the WAN that will be used by the "Outside World" to communicate to servers within the ESXI environment and the other is a Trunk that should then connect to all the VLANs protected by the pfSense box.

**ESXi:**

We've followed [the guide here](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1004252) to setup a Distributed vSwitch in VxRail. we've setup a distributed port group? of VLAN Type VLAN Trunking and with VLAN IDs 0-200:

[image]

To our understanding, this Port Group is what we will attach to pfsense Trunk so that it is able to "read" all the VLAN tagged traffic?

**Trunk on PfSense:**

To create a trunk on pfsense is basically adding the NIC to the pfsense VM. The NIC should be the Port Group we've created above.

[image]

**VLAN on pfSense:**

After that we create a VLAN on pfSense and add a VLAN ID. This VLAN is sitting on the Trunk we've created above. Example below:

[image]

We then add an interface based on this VLAN and give it an IP of `192.168.152.1`

[image]

[image]

**Protected Machine:**

We then create a machine that will be protected by the firewall. So first, we add an NIC to it. The NIC is based on a host network that has a VLAN tag e.g. 152 as seen below.

[image]

[image]

We then assign the protected machine an IP of `192.168.152.10` with a default gateway of `192.168.152.1`.

**Problem Statement:**

Issue is, after doing all this, the protected machine cannot ping its default gateway. The default gateway cannot ping that machine. It's like there is no communication between them at all. We've added a firewall rule to allow all traffic on Interface152 and logged everything but we cannot see any traffic being accepted or rejected.

What could we have missed? The biggest confusion we have is on the VXRail ESXI setup but any correction on pfSense setup is also welcome.

Comment: You can avoid using the virtual VLAN trunk into the VM. Instead, create a port group for each VLAN and add a NIC for each port group. Works a charm.

Comment: If you mean add an NIC to the firewall for each Port Group, then that we've tried and it works. Issue is, its not sustainable because it means every time you have a new VLAN you have to restart the firewall in order to add the NIC. We really really want to avoid that.. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you know which VLANs are bound to show up you could add them in advance. ;-) I haven't used a dSwitch yet but it should be a driver issue.

Comment: That's possible but we are a growing setup so would really really like to avoid adding an NIC every time we have a change in VLANs. 

Else, we raised the issue with EMC last night as its a VXRail box and they said its not up their alley so they've escalated to VMWare... Waiting for the VMWare team to guide us. I will definitely post the solution here when we do get it.

Comment: Is the trunk port on the exsi connected to trunk switch port ?
you also need to confirm that the protected vm is connected to a trunk port that allows vlan 152, or at least an access port configure for vlan 152.
The switch-port configuration seems to be the missing link.

Comment: You should really edit the question to include the full text configurations from the devices. There are other configurations in the devices that may affect what you are trying to do, and we have no way to see them.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I moved jobs soon after this and I kept forwarding the answers that came up here to the team I was working with. Currently I don't have the infrastructure to recreate this scenario but let me find out if it was solved by the team and will update.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a distributed portgroup with VLAN 4095, that port group will keep 802.1Q frame tags set by pfSense virtual machine.

This configuration is known in vSphere parlance as VGT or Virtual Guest Tagging, see [KB 1003806](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003806) and [KB 1004252](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1004252).

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of research/testing as I was trying to set up decent packet capturing: as documented, VGT (port group with VLAN ID 4095) forwards all VLANs from a vSwitch (and probably dSwitch as well) to the VM.

However (poorly documented): **in Windows**, both VMXNET3 and E1000 will - by default - receive all frames from all VLANs but both will also remove all Q tags. Frames being sent out remain untagged, so they'll go to the untagged VLAN on the physical switch.

When you configure a VLAN ID in Advanced Settings on the vNIC, the vNIC starts to filter, only receives frames for that VID (untagged), and tags all outbound frames with this VID. This is exactly the same for VMXNET3 and E1000.

If you install the Intel PROSet utilities with the E1000 vNIC you can set up  *virtual* vNIC instances inside the guest that each provide connectivity to a single VLAN (just like on a physical machine).

Therefore, accessing the full trunk and seeing the 802.1Q tags in packet capture doesn't seem possible in any way in Windows. My impression is that this is a limitation of the virtual vNIC hardware/driver/OS and not of the vSwitch.

**Linux** and **FreeBSD** on the other hand have native VLAN support, using subinterfaces for each VID. My guess is that with VGT you could actually access the VLAN trunk and see the tags in captured frames. I'll try this some time and keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I looked over your configuration, and it seems proper on the pfsense side, that's exactly what I'm doing in my own lab with pfsense, and I have several VMs in production with that type of VLAN trunks.

The issue seems to be that you're using host networking for your VM. I'd configure a new port group on the dSwitch with the settings VLAN and VLAN ID 152, and assign the NIC to that.